# What size should I select for the resistor? I have led and SSR and 24VDC source

Tags: led, resistors, serial, solid-state-relay, 24v

[image]

Could you please clarify this circuit with me? I have selected 90 ohms. Please let me know if I need to do something differently here.

R=(24-30.3)/20mA= 1035ohm and I select 1Kohm

I appreciate any help you can provide.

https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TLP241ATP1F?qs=bUPhaerQQeFDD3ae5xjVlQ%3D%3D
https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Kingbright/APTD3216ZGC?qs=f499HRGa1RmbtnNr4QTsCA%3D%3D

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't put the LED in series with other components, that's just bad design. Now everything depends on everything else and all forward voltages keep adding up. Most often you want to drive 20mA rated LEDs much lower too, around 5mA or so.

Comment: The recommended forward current of the LED in the coupler is 7.5 mA. I would not use more to avoid early degradation. So 2.7 kohm seams to be a good value here.

Comment: Jens, if I use 2.7kohm, the Voltage will drop, and I need 3.3V to turn the LED. Could you please clarify?

Comment: Resistor voltage will be: 24V - 1.3V (optocoupler) - 3V (LED) = 19.7V. For a current of (say) 7.5mA (datasheet recommendation) R = E/I = 19.7V/0.0075= 2.6kΩ. I would use the next lowest common value such as 2.4kΩ. Power dissipation is E^2/R ~= 0.17W so use at least a 1/4-W resistor.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is close. But for all the wrong reasons.

First you say:

"...I have selected 90 Ω. Please let me know if I need to do something differently here.

R = (24-3.3)/20mA = 1035 Ω; I selected 1 kΩ..."

Did you select 90 ohms or 1kohms? It's ambiguous.

More important: your math is wrong. Should be:
R = (24V - 3.3V - 1.27V)/20mA
R = 971.5 ohms

So, yes, 1k was a good choice by luck.

Comment: You are right. I did not know where I got the 90 ohms, but yes, that was my first attempt at math 1kohm. I wanted to make sure that I used the correct resistor- which 1kohm? Thanks.

Comment: Any 1k resistor >= 0.5W